# Google Sheets: Why can't I insert a link (to anything) in a cell containing a formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In any Google Sheet, select a cell containing a formula, for example, `=SUM(1,1)`. You'll see that both the `Insert->Link` menu

[image: Menu Item Disabled]

and the toolbar button for `Insert Link (Ctrl + K)` are disabled.

[image: Toolbar Button Disabled]

Why is that?

**PS:**

1. I've spent considerable time on Google, but I haven't found this issue mentioned anywhere.
2. This problem occurs irrespective of whether the formula has been manually typed in the cell or been populated through Apps Script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This is intended behaviour

If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> when a cell with a formula is highlighted you get the following message:

[image]

Comment: Any ideas why? I mean what harm can possibly come?

Comment: @CodePoet There is a `=hyperlink()` formula, it may lead to conflicts.

Comment: @TheMaster Of course, there is. They could have just blocked links for cells containing that formula. I have a genuine use case and the workaround is non-trivial.

Comment: @CodePoet You can use the `Help > Help Sheets improve` from the Sheets UI to report this to Google :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies to you, but I solved my problem after coming here.  I realized that where I was trying to change the links was actually an "importrange" of another file.  So I have a daily sales ticker that feeds out to our salespeople, but I don't want them to "see" my live file and accidentally make changes.  So I use "importrange" to show just one page of my big file to the salespeople and if they accidentally make a change, it doesn't affect my original formulas.  I was trying to update the links on the "shared version".  Once I went to my original file, I could update the links as expected.  It was ODD though that I was able to delete the link on the shared page.  Just couldn't edit it or create a new link there.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a concatenate formula in the cell. Just replaced it with straight text and it worked again. Seems the hyperlink option is not available for ANY formula and can only work with a text value (maybe numbers / dates also)